# Why isn't my image showing up?

Tags: php, mysql

-------EDIT-------
hi guys, seeing that you solved this problem for me, i thought it would be a good idea to solve the same problem again but on a different page. i cannot get the image to show up.

```
    <?php
$id = $_GET['product_id'];
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM products WHERE serial = '$id'")
or die(mysql_error());  

while($info = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
echo "";

$name = $info['name'];
$description = $info['description'];
$price = $info['price'];
$picture = $info['picture'];

}
?>

<form action="editsuccess.php?product_id=<?php echo $id; ?>" method="post">

Product ID:<br/>
<input type="text" value="<?php echo $id;?>" name="product_id" disabled/>

<br/>

Name:<br/>
<input type="text" value="<?php echo $name;?>" name="name"/>

<br/>

Description:<br/>
<input type="text" value="<?php echo $description;?>" name="description"/>

<br/>

Price:<br/>
<input type="text" value="<?php echo $price;?>" name="price"/>

<br/>

Picture:<br/>
<? echo'<img src="../getImage.php?id=' . $info['serial'] .'"/>'?> 

</br>

<input type="submit" value="Update Product"/>

</form>
```

This is a page where an admin can edit a product from a row in a table. 
The image is not showing up for some reason.

Thanks for any suggestions.

------EDIT ENDS HERE--------

I still cannot get my PHP image to show up even after following the right method in uploading an image to the database. the following code is for displaying the image:

```
<form name="form1">
    <input type="hidden" name="productid" />
    <input type="hidden" name="command" />
</form>

    <table border="0" cellpadding="2px" width="600px">
        <?
            $result=mysql_query("select * from products");
            while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)){

        ?>
        <tr>
            <td><?php '<img src="getImage.php?id=' . $row['serial'] .'"/>'
?>

            </td>
            <td>    <b><a href="products.php?product_id=<?=$row['serial']?>"><?=$row['name']?></a></b><br />
                    <?=$row['description']?><br />
                    Price:<big style="color:green">
                        £<?=$row['price']?></big><br /><br />
                    <input type="button" value="Add to Cart" onclick="addtocart(<?=$row['serial']?>)" />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr><td colspan="2"><hr size="1" /></td>
        <? } ?>
    </table>
```

the `getImage.php` looks like this:

```
...
$link = mysql_connect($host, $user, $passwd);
mysql_select_db($dbName);
$query = 'SELECT picture FROM products WHERE serial="' . $_GET['id'] . '"';
$result = mysql_query($query,$link);
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
echo $row['picture'];
?>
```

only the name, description and price is showing up on the webpage. my MySQL table looks like this:

- serial
- name
- description
- price
- picture (blob)

Comment: is the image stored as a blob? also you should set the headers when outputting as an image, plus you should fix the sql injections.

Comment: yes it is stored as a blob...what do you mean by setting the headerS?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not setting the correct `Content-type` header before echoing out the image data.

You MUST also escape the `$_GET['id']` parameter.

```
// Escape $id
$id = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['id']);   

$link = mysql_connect($host, $user, $passwd);
mysql_select_db($dbName);

// Use the escaped $id
$query = "SELECT picture FROM products WHERE serial='$id'";
$result = mysql_query($query,$link);

if ($result) {
  $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);

  // Set the Content-type
  // This assumes image/jpeg. If you have different image types,
  // you'll need logic to supply the correct MIME type
  // image/jpeg image/png image/gif, etc
  header("Content-type: image/jpeg");
  echo $row['picture'];
}
?>
```

In your main script, it looks like you are merely missing an `echo`

```
        <td><?php '<img src="getImage.php?id=' . $row['serial'] .'"/>'
        // Should be
        <td><?php echo '<img src="getImage.php?id=' . $row['serial'] .'"/>'
        // ------^^^^^^
```

Comment: hi, i now get an error on the getImage.php page which says: The image “http://www.*****.com/musics/getImage.php” cannot be displayed, because it contains errors.

Comment: Well, it looks like you didn't supply an `id`.  Browse to `http://www.yourdomain.com/musics/getImage.php?id=somevalidid`

Comment: That would indicate that 1) there's no record returned for your query, 2) the data in your table is corrupt, 3) you set the wrong Content-type header for the image, or 4) your script is outputting text along with the data for the image thus making the browser think the image is corrupt.

Comment: also check the image is actually stored in the db & not just the path

Comment: the image is stored in the database, i cant think of any other error from my behalf. i am new to php so i really dont know how to go about with this problem...any more help guys?

Comment: @Michael the getImage.php webpage displays an image when i set an id

Comment: @Jahed Do I understand that it is working correctly now, then?

Comment: i need the 1st script to show all the images from the mysql table...the getImage page is the page that sends the image through i believe. it does not show any images..

Comment: HI every1, please read my 1st post...i have editted it with a new problem. i hope you can solve it. thanks

Comment: @Jahed, please post your edit as a new question, since it is a different problem.