# PHP Image Not Coming Up

Tags: php, mysql, error-handling

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why isn't my image showing up?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8187983/why-isnt-my-image-showing-up)

I have a weird problem here. I have this line of code where it works on one page but it doesnt on another. The PHP code is as follows:

PHP Page That Shows Image

```
 <table border=1>
  <tr>
        <td align=center>EDIT</td>
      </tr>
<tr>
<td>
<table>
<?
$id = $_GET['product_id'];
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM products WHERE serial = '$id'");
$info = mysql_fetch_array($result);
?>
<form method="post" action="editsuccess.php">
<input type="hidden" name="id" value="<? echo "$info[name]"?>">
<table border='0' width=100%>
<tr>       
<td>Name</td>
<td>
<input type="text" name="name"
size="20" value="<? echo "$info[name]"?>">
</td>
</tr>

<tr>       
<td>Description</td>
<td>
<input type="text" name="name"
size="20" value="<? echo "$info[description]"?>">
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Price</td>
<td>
<input type="text" name="address" size="40"
value="<? echo "$info[price]"?>">
</td>
</tr>
<tr>       
<td>Image</td>
<td>
<? echo'<img src="../getImage.php?id=' . $info['serial'] .'"/>'?>
</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td align="right">
<input type="submit"
name="submit value" value="Update Product">
</td>
</tr>
</form>
</table>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

PHP Page That Doesnt Show Image

```
 <?php
$id = $_GET['product_id'];

$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM products WHERE serial = '$id'")
or die(mysql_error());  

while($info = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
echo "";

$name = $info['name'];
$description = $info['description'];
$price = $info['price'];
$picture = $info['picture'];
}
?>

<form action="editsuccess.php?product_id=<?php echo $id; ?>" method="post">

Product ID:<br/>
<input type="text" value="<?php echo $id;?>" name="product_id" disabled/>

<br/>

Name:<br/>
<span id="sprytextfield1">
<input type="text" value="<?php echo $name;?>" name="name"/>
<span class="textfieldRequiredMsg">Enter Product Name</span></span><br/>

Description:<br/>
<span id="sprytextfield2">
<input type="text" value="<?php echo $description;?>" name="description"/>
<span class="textfieldRequiredMsg">Enter A Description</span></span><br/>

Price:<br/>
<span id="sprytextfield3">
<input type="text" value="<?php echo $price;?>" name="price"/>
<span class="textfieldRequiredMsg">Enter Price</span><span class="textfieldInvalidFormatMsg">Enter Numbers Only</span></span><br/>

Picture:<br/>
<?php echo '<img src="../getImage.php?id=' . $row['serial'] .'"/>'
?> 

</br>

<input type="submit" value="Update Product"/>

</form>
```

The line of code i am talking about is this one:

```
    <?php echo '<img src="../getImage.php?id=' . $row['serial'] .'"/>'
?>
```

Any ideas why it dont work???

-----EDIT--------

getImage.php code is as follows:

```
    <?php
$host="localhost"; // Host name
$user="****"; // Mysql username
$passwd="****"; // Mysql password
$dbName="**********"; // Database name

// Connect to server and select databse.
mysql_connect("$host", "$user", "$passwd")or die("cannot connect");
mysql_select_db("$dbName")or die("cannot select DB");


$link = mysql_connect($host, $user, $passwd);
mysql_select_db($dbName);
$query = 'SELECT picture FROM products WHERE serial="' . $_GET['id'] . '"';
$result = mysql_query($query,$link);
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
header("Content-type: image/jpeg");
echo $row['picture'];
?>
```

Comment: Are both pages in the same directory?

Comment: yes both files are in the same directory

Comment: I'd need to see the getImage.php file to see. Also check that the "serial" variable is correct on both images.

Comment: the serial variable is correct as it works on one of my pages...all i have done is copied and pasted the same code in another page. i will copy the getimage.php file on my 1st post..please have a look

Comment: You already asked it. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8187983/why-isnt-my-image-showing-up

Comment: i know i have....it worked on that occasion for that page, but its not working on this page. and if you read carefully on the page i asked before, i have asked my question again and have been advised to open up a new thread or question.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, try to avoid short tags (`<?`). Not every webserver is configured to understand them and it kind of conflicts with XML tags (which open with `<?xml`). So replace your `<?` with `<?php` to make sure your code always works on any webserver, regardless of it's configuration setting for short_open_tags.

Second, You're calling `$row['serial']`, but `$row` doesn't appear to be an array (at least it's not defined within the code you pasted here). Are you sure it shouldn't be `$info['serial']`?

But most importantly, whenever you allow user-input (like a $_GET) to determine your SQL query, **always** escape your code with mysql_real_escape_string, like this:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM products WHERE serial = '" . mysql_real_escape_string($id) . "'");
```

Or when you're sure that it's always an integer (e.g. if the field has INT datatype in your database), cast the value as an integer, like so:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM products WHERE serial = " . (int) $id);
```

Comment: the short tags are on the page where it works, the page that doesnt work contains the full tags <?php and i have tried $info['serial']...it still doesnt work. i mean its the exact same code form the page which is displaying the images but for some weird odd reason its not displaying it here.

Answer (score -1):

You shooed to remove  while cicluse

next code 
    while($info = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
    echo "";

```
$name = $info['name'];
$description = $info['description'];
$price = $info['price'];
$picture = $info['picture'];
}
?>
```

change just with

```
$info = mysql_fetch_array($query)
```

Try and tell us does is ok, and does is like you want. :)

Comment: hi Jovanov, i dont really understand what you are saying, but I have now got this: <?php
$id = $_GET['product_id'];

$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM products WHERE serial = '$id'")
or die(mysql_error());  

$info = mysql_fetch_array($query)

?>

Comment: is that what you wanted me to do? if so, nothing works

Comment: any help guys? i really need this working..